# Android App In Market

Tags: android

I have created and application. I want to publish it so that other can install it  and can use it in their devices in free. How To publish  my android app in market so that User can Install and use It??
As I am new I have no Idea.. Waiting For Your Correct Answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with searching in google https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/

Answer (score 1):

The Android developer docs have extensive information on this topic.
Here is as starting point from where you'll find everything you need: [Launch Checklist](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html)

Answer (score 1):

For that ypu have to make signing key for android and build your apk file with that signing key.

you can make signing key using following
just type Following in your window cmd and follow onscreen instructions and remember whatever password you are giving to your keystore file... put any name instead on myname ok. (myname is just a example)

keytool -genkey -v -keystore myname.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

after building your apk file with key follow instructions of following link..

http://mobilesupport.conduit.com/entries/23824611-How-to-submit-an-App-to-Google-Play-store

Comment: Actually Again I have doubt in how to send or export my apk file,, got keystore also

Answer (score 0):

In order to publish your android application to the google play store or any other play store please go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html).

and to upload on the google play store you need to have the publisher's privileges that will cost you USD 25.

More you can follow the instructions at [publish my app](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/) .